# Can I get jenkins xunit result by environment variable?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, googletest, xunit

I want to get unit test results like ${TEST_COUNTS} (which is used in Email-Ext plugin), but I wish to use these results in the post-build phase, not in email. So that I can do somethings, according to whether the unit test failed or passed.

Is there any way I can get this result variable?

I tested that the ${TEST_COUNTS} variable is null in the post-build phase.

Comment: Did you try to set the value of TEST_COUNTS to one of your own env variables? This would make it accessible in the post stage for sure.

Comment: @mkemmerz But doesn't that result in: I only get the env variable which I set myself, not the actual unit test result?